# Can curl act a substitute for programs like Selenium, HtmlUnit, watir etc?

Tags: selenium, curl, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, htmlunit

I need to script some web forms pages and [curl](http://curl.haxx.se) appears to be the answer as it has PHP support.

However the form uses JavaScript menu tabs and I am not quite sure how curl locates the links and clicks them for the other pages to come up. I tried [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and it worked right away. If I use Selenium to locate the IDs of the form elements can curl be scripted to locate those elements, then click them, enter the values and click the submit button?

[Htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is another I'd like to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. curl is not a functional testing tool and does not know anything about html or your page's DOM (document object model) to be able to interact with it. That's not to say you can't use curl and pass the response to something which does understand html...

Comment: I am not interested in a testing tool as such, just something that can be used to control a browser, like filling a web form and submitting it.

Comment: Then yes, it can certainly generate the http post to submit a form to the server and receive the response.

Comment: How does it find the elements to click? Are there examples of how it finds name elements to click or edit form fields?
Selenium appears to do that, but I can't see how curl can do that unless it knows the ids in advance.

Comment: Like I mentioned above curl on its own cannot find DOM elements. You have to do everything manually (ie inspect the result and figure out what request to make).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a late answer. I have worked with htmlunit through Java. It is very handy and useful. You can find lots of toturials online. Also, it partially supports javascripts.